# Getting the title of a picture overlayed onto the picture of a slideshow

Tags: php, html, css

I have a working slideshow with next and previous buttons and I'm trying to work with css to get the descriptions and the title inside the image like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEUv3.jpg. What I've found online is to put the image in the background, but I don't know how to do that with a slideshow.

### HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>dog</p>

    <form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <div class="prev">
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Previous">
        </div>
        <div class="prev">
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Next">
        </div><input name="i" type="hidden" value="1">
        <div class="description">
            <p>dog</p>
            <p></p>



    <a href="?index=<br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in  on line <i>161</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0094</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>245920</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../gallery.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table></font>
    ">next</a>-->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```css
img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 450px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*div.img {
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;*/
    /*width: 450px;
    height: 250px;*/
    /*opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);*/
/*}*/
div.description {
    color:blue;
}
div.prev {
    text-align: left;
}
div.next {
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

### PHP

```php
//if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Previous') {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == 0) {
            $index = count($pic_array) - 1;
            echo "<p> $titles[$index] </p>";
            echo   "<img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />";
        }
        else {
            $index--;
            echo "<p> $titles[$index] </p>";
            echo "<img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$index] . " />";
        }
        echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index'' >";
        echo "<p> $descriptions[$index]";
    }
    if ($_POST['action'] == "Next") {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == count($pic_array) - 1) {
            $index = 0;
            echo "<p> $titles[$index] </p>";
            echo   "<img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />";
        }
        else {
            $index++;
            echo "<p> $titles[$index] </p>";
            echo "<img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$index] . " />";
        }

        echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index' >";
        echo " $descriptions[$index]";

    }

} else {
    $index = 1;
    echo "<p> $titles[$index] </p>";
    echo  "<img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />";
    echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <div class="prev">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        </div>
        <div class="prev">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">
        </div>';
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index' >";
    echo "<div class='description'
                <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
          </div>";


}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: your code looks mess up. do you have a working version we can view online?

Comment: The html is from copying the element from the web page, you would have to be logged onto the server to be able to view it online. The php contains the html I Wrote.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a `<form>` to run your slideshow? Do you intend for the user to make a new page request for each slide?

Comment: How about using jQuery or bootstrap carousel?

Comment: Yes there is a reason, I'm working on a training task for a job and they want me to do it this way and then the next step will be to make a slideshow with jquery. Currently I just need to make it look like the example image shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text to overlay the image you need to absolute position the text inside of a container that has `position: relative;` applied to it. This container element should be one of the outer elements of your slideshow's markup.

Why? If you don't the text overlay could end up anywhere on your page.

Here is basic example.

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250">
  <div class="slide-caption">
    <h3 class="slide-title">Slide Title</h3>
    <p>
      Slide caption. Slide caption. Slide caption. Slide caption. Slide caption. Slide caption.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slide-title {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}
.slide-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6fsqfqv/).

Our `.slide` element has `display: inline-block;` so it will wrap our image nicely regardless of the image's size. This way `.slide` is the same size as the image. `.slide` has `position: relative;` applied to it so any absolute positioned elements stay within this element.

The magic for the caption placement is in the absolute positioning of our `.slide-caption` container element. `bottom: 0;` sucks it to the bottom of it's parent element `.slide`. `right: 0; left: 0;` stretch it to the full width of `.slide`.

There's a number of ways to achieve your overlay text. This is one approach.

Comment: I just tried that and the text is still below the image.

Comment: echo "<div class='slide'>
            <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
            <div class='caption'>
                <h3 class='title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
            </div>
         </div>";

Comment: .slide {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.slide img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.title {
    margine:0 0 1rem;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}

Comment: When I inspect the div.slide it is bigger than the picture itself?

Comment: I fixed it I had to add an auto width and height.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I'm guessing you might have had some other CSS interfering. It looks like you implemented by example code almost 1:1 so you shouldn't have had any issues.